# Kusto calculate the minutes since last event

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I am converting a Splunk Dasboard to a Kusto Dash board

Below is the Splubk Query that give me the minites since as 60
`index=V source=c:\\files\\build\\* | head 1 | eval minutesSince=round((now() - _indextime)/60,0) | table minutesSince`

I try to create the same in Kusto but the time is not matching gives me 0 minutesSince. But the Data is the same in Splunk and Kusto. Not sure what part of the Query should I correct. Thanks for the support.

````
| extend minutesSince = (now() - ingestion_time())/60
| project minutesSince,BuildId
| limit 1```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could try something like the following:

for the entire table:

```
TableName
| summarize minutes_since_last_ingestion = (now() - max(ingestion_time())) / 1m
```

or, per record:

```
TableName
| extend minutes_since_ingestion = (now() - ingestion_time()) / 1m
```

Comment: Thanks I could run the Query for the per record and get the details. But the result is diff because I think there could be delay in the data Sync. I will verify the log files manually.